# Checkbox not displaying in custom row

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom row that is inflated in a custom adapter, but the checkboxes in the custom row aren't visible.

Here's the xml code for the row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="7dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/delete_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/company_symbol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textColor="@color/md_grey_600"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/company_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textColor="@color/md_grey_800"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I expect the checkbox to be displayed to the left of the row but here's what the result looks like:

[image: Complete ListView]

Any help on why the checkboxes aren't displaying would be appreciated

Comment: dont use weight and wrap content at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox** use **CheckBox**

it is already written in its docs

**This will automatically be used when you use *CheckBox* in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.**

```
  <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/delete_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is said above, don't use wrap content and weight. Here you should use `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
android:id="@+id/delete_checkbox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:weightSum="4"
android:paddingTop="7dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/delete_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/company_symbol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textColor="@color/md_grey_600"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/company_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textColor="@color/md_grey_800"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Hope it may helps.!**